# Matrix of lists

Tags: c++

I have two structures

```
struct Edge{
        int v1;
    int v2;
        int weigt;

    Edge(int v1_tmp, int v2_tmp, int weight_tmp);
};

struct GraphList{
        int V;
    int E;
    list<Edge>* mylist;
}

GraphList::GraphList(GrafMatrix* graph){
    V=graph->V;
    E=graph->E;

    for (int i=0; i<V; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<V; j++){
            if (graph->matrix[i][j]==1) mylist[i].push_back( Edge(i+1, j+1, graf->weights[i][j]) );
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong? When `i=0` and `j=1`, there's an  error. I tried `lista = new list<Krawedz>()` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dereferencing a pointer which was never allocated any space. Notice `list<Edge>* mylist`. You should use `new` as

```
mylist = new list<Edge>[k];  //declare an array of k list<Edge>.
```

Then you will be able to access mylist[0] ,...., mylist[k-1].